# Go webserver how is the performance stability, in terms of long run stability compared to Tomcat, Apache?

Tags: php, ruby, apache, tomcat, go

I have been thinking instead of using:

- Tomcat
- Apache
- Lightweight webserver
- PHP
- Ruby
- JSP

Why not switch my projects to Go language. Because there i have:

- webserver built in
- i do not even need to depend on PHP, Ruby, JSP
- Go solves cross-platform such as: runs on FreeBSD, Linux, Solaris (Windows, Mac, Android, Tizen)
- nor Apache nor Tomcat nor other webserver maintainence
- speed of browser would be extreamly faster then other web server scripting languages.

But one thing i am worried about, which is the stablity of Go webserver compared to other webservers.

Has anyone done this before or am i alone building such projects for production releases?

Comment: Ruby has a webserver in the standard library too (`require 'webrick'`), but I wouldn't necessarily expose that directly to users.

Comment: Most webservers like Go's aren't designed to be full-featured servers; people generally run them as application servers behind something like Apache or nginx. That way, the more configurable frontend can handle things like caching, load balancing, serving of static data, and so forth.

Comment: Doesn't `Bill the Lizard` just _love_ closing questions that are actually useful on StackOverflow?! Based on some stupid technicality. This site is meant to be a practical question-answer forum for real world developers and this question does a great job at being one (and so does the answer). I'm sure he feels he's doing something incredibly useful with his life. This isn't the first time I ran into this situation - hence this comment out of sheer years-old `wat`ing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are no stability problem.

I have a few webservers 100% in go that run for months, serving about a million queries per month without any problem (mostly json, through GET, POST, and websockets).

They're on 64 bits ubuntu servers but I guess you would have difficulties producing the so much gossiped about 32 bits bug, especially with a web server.

Don't use a front-end if you have no specific reason : It's easy to make a complete web application just using Go.

You will be far from alone. In my opinion Go is especially well suited to build long running servers. Goroutines and channels makes it really easy to handle both user requests and long term tasks (or, for example, do the postreatment of user queries after you answered the http query, which isn't so easy in php and is too many LOC in java if you want to do it properly).

Comment: +1 For talking out of the experience on the ground.

Comment: Are you using a specific tool to keep alive and monitor you go processes on Ubuntu ?

Comment: Not today. I use a service that alerts me if one stop responding but as I have never experienced a crash in prod I don't feel the pressure now. I guess you could use a standard tool if you need to. I found that the debug cycle is different than the one of, for example, java or php : you detect the errors really fast, either while compiling or at first tests (mostly array index errors or map not allocated...) while in most other languages errors are often hidden. I like to use the "go test" function tool too. The fact that the compilation is fast and included in the operation makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the Build in Webserver and set up a Reverse Proxy like Varnish, or let Nginx act as Proxy?

http://wiki.nginx.org/ReverseProxyCachingExample

Comment: Why? Why would you? It adds another layer of abstraction that has to be maintained and updated. And that’s what the questioner seemed to try to avoid. Adding caching does not help in stability, just performance. Only for cache-lifetime may it provide additional “stability”; hiding down-time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nginx as the front-end and make sure that you are using the 64bit version of Go. The 32bit version has severe stability problems which are a show stopper for any long-running processes.

Comment: Could you please provide a couple of links to relevant bug reports and/or newsgroups/ML discussions?  I'm also interested in the researching the original question, and while your statement is strong it appears to be a bit of hand-waving; claims like this one are expected to be backed by data.

Comment: Here's a thread discussing problems with 32 bit.  http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/ab1971bb9459025d/64241d28b02fa0db?lnk=gst

Comment: Please note that this bug may also arise on 64 bits servers but is so rare that you certainly won't see it, even on 32 bits. It took years and a specific memory usage pattern to detect it.